# C# Web APi not returning Exceptions only get 500 Internal server error

Tags: c#, .net

I've developed an API that requests another provider's API. If this provider returns an exception, I want to send the user an object I've created that includes the existing Exception property.

```
      [HttpPost("notification/sendDataForProvider")]
    public async Task<MyResponse> SendEmail([FromBody] EmailInfo emailInfo, [FromHeader] string token)
    {
        IntAction action = new someProviderClass();
        IntResponse payload = await action.Start();
        return payload;
    }



   public class MyResponse {
    public int Code;
    public string Message;
    public object? Exception;
   }
```

So im catching the error that coming from "action.start()" returing MyResponse object with the exception in the property and when sending it back through the API im getting is 500 interal server error

this is the object that should returned:
[image]

I'm encountering an issue in C# where I'm unable to return my custom object. Instead of receiving my object with the desired properties exception property, I'm consistently getting a 500 Internal Server Error

thanks

Comment: "I want to send the user an object I've created that includes the existing Exception property." - VERY careful with that - this generally is a bad idea. It may expose security relevant information. The way you handle this is by telling the user an internal error happened WITHOUT details, and log the details separately, then fix the issue. 500 indicates somethig happened you did not foresee - that should never expose any details to end users.

Comment: Consider an Exception Handling Middleware, that logs exceptions for you but creates error results that don't open an attack vector.

Comment: I would advise you to use [Hellang Middleware Tutorial](https://andrewlock.net/handling-web-api-exceptions-with-problemdetails-middleware/) to handle this.

Comment: `So im catching the error...` The code you posted is *not* doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 500 Internal Server Error is a Http Status code that returned in case of there is a unexpected exception occurred during the execution of request.

To avoid getting the 500 Internal Server Error try to set the customized Http Response Status code instead of the default 500.

Method return type should be IHttpActionResult

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SendEmail([FromBody] EmailInfo emailInfo, [FromHeader] string token)
```

Method return Content object with the HttpStatus code in case of exception

```
return Content(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, payload);
```